# Selenium python interact with remote browser in a docker container using host browser

Tags: python, docker, selenium

Is there any way to display when i want what is happening and also interact with a browser in a docker container controlled by selenium (python)?
I mean I have this scenario:
I want to get a website using tor browser by python selenium and I want to show to a remote client what it's happening on the tor browser and interact with it like insert input text and click buttons

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.